# Importing World Map image changes color in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, import, imagery, color

I am having a hard time finding a world relief map with "lighter" ocean colors that will actually display as such in Arc.

This is the image I download from the web

[image: This is the image I download from the web]

but this is how it displays in ArcGIS.

[image: , but this is how it displays in ArcGIS.]

Comment: Where did you download the world map? It looks like the map is 50% (?) transparent. Did you check the "symbology" in ArcGIS of the layer? Can you adjust transparency or min/max values?

Comment: You... You're good you. Transparency never even crossed my mind. The map was downloaded from Natural Earth, so I don't think it was different there, but never thought to try to adjust that in Arc. Still doesn't get me back to that color, but much better than I was.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I downloaded the [Natural Earth II with Shaded Relief and Water- Map](http://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/10m-raster-data/10m-natural-earth-2/).

Imported to ArcGIS it looks like your second map, because ArGIS automtically stretches the color histogram. You can change this by `right-click to the layer` > `Properties` > `Symbology`. If you select `Stretch` `Type: None` the oceans are light blue.

You could also play around with `Properties` > `Display`: `Brightness` or `Transperancy`